# caches domain user on local PC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, domain-controller, user-accounts

We have a fully working domain in UK and around the world we have user who use VPN ( checkpoint) to connect to or domain.

One of the user in USA has a laptop which he never logged on to before ( it does caches the user login details). Does anyone know how to cache user login information on this laptop.

I have tried netdom trust to add this user to the laptop but i was not able to do this.

At the moment user is logging in with a local administrator account and then using VPN to log on to our domain but when it comes to accessing files on domain user get access deieded.

When user try to login it gets `There are currently no log on servers available to service the logon request`

Does anyone know how to add user.

Answer (score 0):

Without plugging the computer into the network the domain is on the only way I can think of that would kind of work is to have a map drive to the server they need access to that uses the users domain credentials.

This would still require them to log into the computer using a local account but would give them access to files on the domain.

Comment: When user login into local account then they use the vpn to logon to our domain. I need to cache the domain account details on this pc.

Comment: So the VPN connection is initiated before the user logs into the computer?